# How to redirect stdout in real time from child process

Tags: node.js, process, pipe, node-webkit, nw.js

I have a long running child process that has

> {stdio: 'inherit'}

So, I can see whatever it's doing in the console.

How can I redirect this information so it'll show up on my node-webkit app?

Answer (score 0):

Simply handle data events from the STDOUT stream in some way.

```
childProc.stdout.on('data', function (chunk) {
  // Write chunk to the page using whatever normal method you like
});
```